# ADAL acquire token with username and password

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to acquire token from azure AD from Xamarin Form application. I am using ADAL 4+ and I don't want user to login every time when app is launch.
Is there anyway to refresh or acquire token programmatically when application relaunch after user already successfully login.

Due to ADAL no longer have userPasswordCredientian(). I couldn't find any alternative solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once ADAL.NET has acquired a token for a user, it caches it, along with a refresh token. Then next time the application wants a token, it should first call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to verify if an acceptable token is in the cache. If there is a token but it has expired, `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` will use the cached refresh token in order to refresh the access token and if no token is in the cache, then an interactive call might be necessary to have the user sign-in again.

[Here's some more information on how this works in ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#acquiretokenasync-gets-token-from-the-cache)

This is the recommended call pattern, do an AT silent call first, and catch the AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException (because a token was not found), then do an AT interactive call.

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult result=null;
try
{
 result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException)
{
 if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently
     || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.InteractionRequired)
  {
   result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri,
                                       new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
  }
}
```

I would recommended moving to MSAL...here's [documentation on the differences between ADAL and MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal) and [specifics on the username/password flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) in MSAL and how to migrate from [ADAL.NET 4.x to MSAL.NET 2.x](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-2-released#migrating-from-adalnet-3x-or-4x-to-msalnet-2x) and the just released [MSAL v3 api](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#configuring-an-app-got-simpler).

Comment: Thank for helping Jenny.
I will test it and let you know.